# CSS nth-child Hover Issue

Tags: css, css-selectors

I've finally figured out how to get nth-child to work in my particular css code. However, I'm still having a small issue. The nth-child hover color css I added is showing up underneath the actual div.

I'VE TRIED SEVERAL VARIATIONS WITH NO LUCK. Can anyone suggest a fix?

Current CSS:

```
li#home-page.page-wrapper-li>div:nth-child(2):hover {
    background-color:#993366 !important;
    height: 160px;
}
```

Comment: Please don't include short links. Can you make a fiddle instead?

Comment: Please, before you try anything, use a proper way of selecting your elements and stuff. :x

Comment: If `li#home-page.page-wrapper-li` can't be reduced to `#home-page`, you're doing something *badly* wrong.

Comment: Provide jsfiddle and we´re all happy.

Comment: Dude. Are you sure you want that video in the background? just keeping a conversation here while we wait for the fiddle...

Answer (score 1):

I think that you need to change your hover:

remove the background-color from your hover above and set this new hover:

```
#home-page > div:nth-child(2):hover .div-bg-color {background-color:#993366; opacity:1;}
```

**EDIT**

Sorry, as you have qualified your li to a different level you will need to use this:

```
li#home-page.page-wrapper-li > div:nth-child(2):hover .div-bg-color {background-color:#993366; opacity:1;}
```

As pointed out in the comments though `li#home-page.page-wrapper-li` will be a lot more inefficient than just `#home-page`